# How to logoff all windows 10 users except current logged in user?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am creating an windows software. In that I need to logoff all users except current user who is logged in.

I have tried using power shell command in my WPF application which works some time and and some time it doesn't.
find the command below:

```
quser | Select-String "Disc" | ForEach {logoff ($_.toString() -split ' +')[2]
```

When I click a button in my WPF Apllication all users except current should be loggedOff.

Comment: _I need to logoff all users except current user who is logged in_ means logoff everyone except **_you_** ?

Comment: exactly @Theo. That is what I need

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted will only log off *disconnected* users. To log off everyone except the current user you'll have to remove the current user from the `quser` output:

```
(quser | Select-Object -Skip 1) -notlike ">$env:USERNAME *"
```

and then log off the remaining sessions:

```
... | ForEach-Object { logoff ($_ -split ' +')[-5] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansgars answer did not quite work for me, what worked was:

```
(quser) -notlike ">$env:USERNAME *" | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { logoff ($_ -split ' +')[-5] }
```

This did the trick as I had to exclude the current user first from the quser listing.